# Add vertices and duplicate names

Tags: python, igraph

I'm working with IGRAPH for python.
I want to know is there any way to insert vertex is not there

E.g.:

```
import igraph

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    g = igraph.Graph()
    g.add_vertex(1)
    g.add_vertex(1)
    for vertex in g.vs():
        print vertex
```

Result:

```
 igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f783e9b5a00>,0,{'name': 1})
 igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f783e9b5a00>,1,{'name': 1})
```

I checked the documentation, but could not find any way to solve the problem.

I think that index = `g.vs.select("name_eq")` or index = `g.vs(name_eq="?")` or `vector with added records` can solve, but I want a cleaner solution.

E.g.: But its not good

```
added_vertices = set()

def add_vertex(g, name, _type="verb"):
    if name not in added_vertices:
        added_vertices.add(name)
        g.add_vertex(name, type=_type)
```

I need read file in this format:

```
word_1 verb_1 word_2
word_2 verb_2 word_3
word_3 verb_1 word_4
....
```

Read by:

```
f = open('input.in', 'r')
g = igraph.Graph()
for line in f:
    left, verb, right = line.strip().split("\t")
    g.add_vertex(verb, type="verb")
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: By "I want to know is there any way to insert vertex is not there" do you mean you only want the vertex to be inserted if it isn't already there?

Comment: @s16h I have edited the post again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g.vs.find(name=...)` finds the first vertex with the given name and returns it, or throws a `ValueError` if such a vertex is not found. You can use this to construct a function that adds or finds a vertex with a given name:

```
def add_or_find_vertex(g, name):
    try:
        return g.vs.find(name=name)
    except ValueError:
        g.add_vertex(name)
        return g.vs.find(name=name)
```